# Add category to uploaded image media - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to upload media (image) with Wordpress Rest API. This is my code:

```
function upload_cover(WP_REST_Request $request) {

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload('cover', 0);
    $event = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type'   => 'poster',
        'meta_input'  => array(),
        'post_category' => array('poster')
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $event );
    wp_set_post_terms($post_id, 'poster', 'category');
}
```

and I want to add `poster` category to it
Everything works and image is uploaded, but it does not apply the category.
 For the categories for images, I am using this plugin `Media Library Categories`.

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_set_object_terms($attachment_id, 'poster', 'category', true);
```

is the answer.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/